# propertyChanged for server calculated property not firing anymore in 1.4.12

Tags: breeze

i'm displaying a server calculated value to the enduser by using propertyChanged event.
i was using breeze 1.4.8 and i'm using the productivity stack (ms sql, web api, ef)
It was working fine.
Recently i've updated to 1.4.12 and i recognized that this event doesn't get fired anymore.
The property "A_ProvisionTotal" gets calculated serverside only.

```
<snip>
    var token = vm.transaction.entityAspect.propertyChanged.subscribe(propertyChanged);
    function propertyChanged(propertyChangedArgs) {
        var propertyName = propertyChangedArgs.propertyName;
        if (vm.transaction.tblEmployees.CalculationMethod == "A" && propertyName == "A_ProvisionTotal")
            logSuccess('Provision neuberechnet' + '<br/>' + 'Aktuell: ' + $filter('number')(vm.transaction.Provision, 2), true);
</snip>
```

Let me know if this is a known regression and if you need more snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts for how you could accomplish your desired functionality.

1. The entity could remember the last calculated value in a private field. Then whenever the recalculation gets triggered, you can compare the new value to the last calculated value and if there is no change, ignore the new calculated value.
2. Alternatively, you could define the properties involved in your calculation as ES5 properties in the entity ctor function and then trigger the calculation in the setter of the relevant properties, when they get set with a new value. More information here: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities#es5-property. ES5 properties are convenient if you want to build behavior such as your calculation into setters.

Answer (score 0):

### Update 3

This is not a bug - see the response to this post that describes this as a documented and deliberate behavior.

### Update 2 June 2014

I overlooked a key fact in your question ... one that only became clear to me after I looked at the [code you included in your comments](http://pastebin.com/cpU5G1VH).  Let me extract the key pieces for other readers:

Your test issues a query, then saves an unrelated change to the server (where the property-of-interest is updated server-side), then checks if that telltale property-of-interest raises `propertyChanged` when the save result is merged back into cache.

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("Orders").where('id', 'eq', 10248);
query.using(em).execute().then(querySucceeded).then(checkPropertyChanged).fin(start);

// querySucceed receives order 10248, updates an unrelated property (so you can save), 
// wires up a propertyChanged listener and saves, returning the saveChanges promise

function checkPropertyChanged(saveResults) {
    var saved = saveResults.entities[0];

        // this passes because the server-side change to `Freight` was returned
        ok(saved && saved.Freight() === 1200.00,
            "freight got changed serverside");

        // this fails because Breeze did not notify you that the `Freight` had changed
        ok(notifications[0].propertyName  === "Freight",
            "notified serverside change of Freight Property");
}
```

Summarizing, you expected that a property change **on the server** would trigger a `propertyChanged` notification **on the client** when the entity data are **re-retrieved from the server** as a by-product of `saveChanges`.

*Do I have that right?*

Our documentation was not clear on whether the merge of query, save, and import entity results would raise `propertyChanged`.

I discussed internally and confirmed that **these operations SHOULD raise `propertyChanged`**. I also wrote another (somewhat simpler) test that reveals the bug you discovered: that merged save results may not raise `propertyChanged`.

We'll look into it and tell you when we've fixed it. Thanks for discovering it.

### Original

We have regression tests that show that the Breeze `EntityAspect.propertyChanged` event is raised in v.1.4.12. For example, you can see it at work in the [DocCode sample, "basicTodoTests.js"](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/basicTodoTests.js); scroll to: "Breeze propertyChanged raised when any property changes".

Can you confirm that it really is a Breeze failure? Perhaps the property you are changing is not actually an entity property? Sometimes you think you are changing an entity (e.g, your `Transaction` entity) but the thing whose property you changed isn't actually an entity. Then the problem is that the data you thought would be mapped to a `Transaction` was not ... and you can start looking for that quite different problem.

In any case, I suggest that you write a small test to confirm your suspicion ... most importantly for yourself ... and then for us. That will help us discover what is different about your scenario from our scenarios. We'll fix it if you can find it. Thanks.

Comment: hi ward, thanks for the suggestion
my observations so far:
 - exported the working version again from git. run it. -> ok
 - then i've replaced breeze client 1.4.8 with 1.4.12. -> not ok
then i created a testcase using the northwindSave cases (because they also use the serverside BeforeSaveEntity which i also use....)
And guess what, it didn't work with breeze 1.4.8 and with 1.4.12. instead propertyChanged gives me back a propertyName "Null".
So the i've checked (diff'ed) the wireformat of the working and not working solution and it was the same...
so so far i've no clue what could be wrong

Comment: the testcase is here: http://pastebin.com/cpU5G1VH 
i've put it into the saveNorthwindTests.js
To make it work you also need a piece of BeforeSaveEntity-Code: http://pastebin.com/9q6Y1YXT

Comment: any news on this? for now it's not a biggie for me because i'm staying with the old working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm not sure that this is a bug. Property change events DO get fired during a save merge but the property name parameter is documented as being 'null' when fired as a result of a save.

http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html#event_propertyChanged

From the API Docs for the '**propertyName**' parameter returned by EntityAspect.propertyChanged:

*The name of the property that changed. This value will be 'null' for operations that replace the entire entity. This includes queries, imports and saves that require a merge. The remaining parameters will not exist in this case either.*

What may have happened between 1.4.8 and 1.4.13 is that we actually implemented our design spec more carefully and probably introduced your breaking behavior. ( which we should have documented as such but likely missed).

### Update by Ward

I [updated the DocCode test](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/saveTodosTests.js) which first confirmed the behavior described in your question and then confirmed the documented behavior.

We do regret that we apparently neglected to implement the documented behavior earlier and that we didn't mention the breaking change in our release notes (since updated).

Here's that test:

```
asyncTest("propertyChanged raised when merged save result changes a property", 3, function () {
    var em = newTodosEm(); 
    var todo = em.createEntity('TodoItem', {Description: "Saved description" });

    em.saveChanges().then(saveSucceeded).catch(handleFail).finally(start);

    ok(todo.entityAspect.isBeingSaved, "new todo is in the act of being saved");

    // This change should be overwritten with the server value when the save result is returned
    // even though the entity is in an Added state and the MergeStrategy is PreserveChanges
    // because save expects to merge server values into an entity it is saving
    todo.Description("Changed on client before save returns");

    var descriptionChanged = false;
    todo.entityAspect.propertyChanged.subscribe(function (changeArgs) {
        // Watch carefully! The subscription is called twice during merge
        // 1) propertyName === "Id" (assigned with permanent ID)
        // 2) propertyName === null (WAT?)  
        // and not called with propertyName === "Description" as you might have thought.
        // Actually 'null' means "merged a lot of properties"
        // Documented: http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html#event_propertyChanged
        // The reason for this: don't want to fire a ton of events on whole entity load
        // especially when merging many entities at the same time.
        if (changeArgs.propertyName === null || changeArgs.propertyName === 'Description') {
            descriptionChanged = true;
        }
    });

    function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
        var saved = saveResult.entities[0];
        // passes
        equal(saved && saved.Description(), "Saved description",
            "the merge after save should have restored the saved description");

        // fails
        ok(descriptionChanged,
            "should have raised propertyChanged after merge/update of 'Description' property");
    }
});
```

Comment: well my app is relying on this notification on serverside change of properties. it displays this serverside calculated value to the user immediately after it got calculated thanks to the propertyChanged Event (because its crucial for the user to know the result). nobody should be able to change the calculation of this property, thats why i'm doing it serverside. i really would appreciate if this would work as well in current breeze versions.

Comment: Not sure I understand, the event still fires, it's just that the propertyName in the event will be null when fired as a result of a save operation.

Comment: Yes but as Ward indicated it is a breaking behaviour.
i'm all for performance, thats fine.
So now imho my options are either adding another field to the database where i can indicate this change to the client or i can use a "model only" - property which is not in the database. for the latter i would appreciate some help because i couldn't find any documentation.